# Angular scope variable is not updated

Tags: angularjs

I have some weird problem. Below app needs to do following things:

- play selected song after clicking button with play_song function
- when a song is finished, it should automatically start next song from playlist - if song is last one, it will start from the start

Everything seems to work fine, play_song button works correctly, when song is finished, it automatically start next one. But, the first time it starts another song, play_button function does not work anymore, it just does not update $scope.song, despite the fact that after checking it in console it does seem to be updated correctly. Please help as I cannot find the reason of described behaviour.

```
angular.module('playItApp', ['playItServices'])

    .controller('songList', ['$scope', 'songsService', function($scope, songsService){
        $scope.playlist = songsService.query();
        $scope.song = null;
        $scope.current_song = null;
        $scope.play_song = function(index){
            $scope.song = $scope.playlist[index];
            $scope.current_song = index;
        }
    }])

    .directive('source', function(){
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                'src': '@'
            },
            link: function(scope, element, attrs){
                scope.$watch('src', function(value){
                    document.getElementById('track').load();
                });
            }
        }
    })

    .directive('audio', function(){
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs){
                element[0].onended = function() {
                    if (scope.current_song + 1 < scope.playlist.length){
                        scope.song = scope.playlist[scope.current_song+1];
                        scope.current_song ++;
                    } else {
                        scope.song = scope.playlist[0];
                        scope.current_song = 0;
                    }
                    scope.$apply();
                }
            }
        }
    });


<h1>Playlist</h1>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="play in playlist">
        {{ play }}
        <span class="fa fa-play" ng-click="play_song($index)"></span>
    </li>
</ul>
<div ng-if="song">
    <h2>{{ song.title }}</h2>
    <audio id="track" controls autoplay>
        <source ng-src="{{ song.path }}" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a scope issue.

Be careful with scope inheritance. inheritance means that you'll get to access to properties from the parent scope, but everything you set will be in the current scope.

Therefore, childScope.song accesses parentScope.song, until childScope.song is assigned. And when childScope.song is assigned, parentScope.song remains unchanged.

The easiest solution here would be to put all your values inside an object.

```
$scope.data = {};
$scope.data.song = ...
[etc.]
```

See codepen below (don't mind the sample mp3s and the filter that was necessary to play mp3s from external sources).

http://codepen.io/jlowcs/pen/embgwV

Comment: Thank you very much! It works! Unfortunately I am not sure I understand totally why this happened though. It is javascript or angular specific issue? Also, is there any other way to tackle this problem? You mentioned that creating wrapper object is the easiest, but I would be more than happy to find out about those more difficult too, maybe thanks to this I will understand this problem better.

Comment: It's a common angular issue related to how it creates scopes using prototype inheritance. The less easy way and better way of solving this problem is to use the controller in your markup (using controllerAs) instead of the scope. Just assign to this.song instead of scope.song in your controller and use ``ng-controller="song list as ctrl"`` and ``{{ctrl.song}}`` in your markup. You'll also have to pass some of your variables as attributes (using ``=``) to your ``audio`` directive.

Comment: It turned out, that it is also possible to correct above issue by using scope.$parent.variable = value in directive, what do you think about this solution?

Comment: A directive should not assume anything about what's in the parent scope. It should be self-contained. That's why my easiest solution is not great. Using $parent is even worse, because, if you happen to add a directive in between, you might add a scope and therefore break your code (and need to change it to $parent.$parent...). Just avoid using $parent.

Comment: I see, I would like to do it better, that's why I would like to implement you suggestion with as ctrl. But first I tried to just override the scope in my directive by doing:                                                                                              scope: {
 'current_song': '=current',
        'playlist': '=',
 'song': '='
} and changing my audio tag to:                                                                       <audio id="track" controls autoplay current="{{ current_song }}" song="{{ song }}" playlist="{{ playlist }}"> which causes [$parse:syntax]

Comment: Don't use curly braces with data binding (``=``)

Comment: Thanks for your help, now everything is working as it should, I actually like controller as syntax and I will probably give up $scope alltogether, I believe it makes the code more legible.